# Combine multiple regex expressions into a single line

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the following Regex expressions into a single line.

```cs
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[^a-z0-9\s-!/\-_\.\*\(\)']", ""); // Remove all non valid chars          
    filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"\s+", " ").Trim(); // convert multiple spaces into one space  
    filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"\s", "_"); // //Replace spaces by dashes
```

Comment: @sln No, [it is fine](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5ea-z0-9%5cs-!%2f%5c-_%5c.%5c*%5c%28%5c%29%27%5d&i=%23%40%24%23%5e). The formatting was wrong.

Comment: Invalid range end in character class `[\s-<<<HERE>>>!]`  https://regex101.com/r/ydfdtV/1 Maybe C# ignores the `-`, no other engine does

Comment: var filename = "test".Trim();
 filename = new Regex(@"[^a-z0-9\s-!/-.*()']|\s+").Replace(filename, "");
Regex.Replace(filename, @"\s", "_");

Comment: Bad range and character range is out of order `[^a-z0-9\s-!/-.*()']` https://regex101.com/r/GnylOD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[^a-z0-9\s!/_.*()'-]|^\s+|\s+$|(\s+)", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? "_" : "");
```

The regex matches

- `[^a-z0-9\s!/_.*()'-]|` - any char but lowercase ASCII letters, digits, whitespace, `!`, `/`, `_`, `.`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `'` and `-`, or
- `^\s+|` - start of string and then one or more whitespaces, or
- `\s+$|` - one or more whitespaces and then end of string
- `(\s+)` - Group 1: one or more whitespaces in any other context.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is a `_` char, else, the replacement is an empty string (the match is removed).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Ea-z0-9%5Cs!%2F_.*%28%29%27-%5D%7C%5E%5Cs%2B%7C%5Cs%2B%24%7C%28%5Cs%2B%29&i=%20%20%23%40%24%23%5EaX12-%2F%27%22%3F%3C%3E%7B%7D%5B%5D%20%20%20).